# Search variable for tags

Tags: jquery, loops, variables, tags, selector

I have some html that I'm acquiring through an ajax call.  I am assigning the html string to a variable.  What I would like to do is just search this variable, not the whole document, for pre tags and display the text.  What is the correct way to do this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var rawtext = htmlstringwithpretags
    $(rawtext).find('pre').each(function () {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Comment: can you give us an example ?

Comment: Use `substring()` and `indexOf()`

Comment: what is the issue you are having right here with your implementation?

Comment: @code-jaff  The issue is I want to perform the search on a variable not on the markup.  It is only working when I have the text in a div within the body.  I can't dump the html straight into the body.  Some security in MS is preventing me from doing it this way.

Comment: @Jotter checkout my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you might want to look at the [$.parseHTML()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/)

```
var rawtext = "hello wold<pre>pre text content</pre>";
var html = $.parseHTML(rawtext);

$.each(html, function(i, el){
    if( 'PRE' == el.nodeName ){ alert(el) }
});
```

Comment: This is it. I changed alert to:  alert($(el).text())};  since I need the text.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`htmlstring` has one `pre` tag

```
var rawtext = "hello wold<pre>pre text content</pre>";
alert($("<div>"+rawtext+"</div>").find('pre').text());
```

`htmlstring` has many `pre` tag and you want to iterate, then use this

```
$("<div>"+rawtext+"</div>").find('pre').each(function() {
       alert($(this).text());

  });
```

Comment: This is creating a new div for the variable?  Can I iterate using .each here?

Comment: you mean, that htmlstring has more than one pre tag and you want to get all values?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("<div>"+rawtext+"</div>").find("pre").each(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```